# android studio error Unable to locate adb

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy iniciandome en el desarrollo de app con android studio con jre y jvm que copio a continuación.

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 8, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Al momento de ejecutar un proyecto, me da el siguiente error

```
Unable to locate adb
```

Lo reporte a google y he buscado en otros foros donde afirman que el avast (en mi caso) habria eliminado el archivo adb.exe, busque en el baul de virus y no lo veo. Desactive el antivirus, desintale e instale el android studio y sigo con el mismo problema.

Ademas, ejecute rebulding y clear project, obteniendo el mismo error. 
Si alguien lo pudo resolver o me puede orientar o pasarme un foro en el que este resuelto, sera bien agradecido. 
Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es posible que no tengas configurado el SDK de android para tu proyecto.

Para configurarlo ve a `File` > `Project Structure` y dentro de los ajustes del proyecto, en el apartado `Project SDK` configura la versión de Android que necesites

[image: Project SDK]

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema, aunque en mi caso me salía el mensaje "unable to locate adb" pero me permitía iniciar el emulador. Después de probar soluciones que pasaban por borrar la carpeta platform-tools y reinstalar Android SDK Platform-tools (que no me solucionaron el problema) o incluso reinstalar otros componentes, reiniciar etc... esta solución si me funcionó.

Comment: @carlosdag28 en mi caso también se inicia el emulador sin problema, pero es molesto que todo el rato aparezca el error. Aunque no sé si tiene alguna implicación real

Comment: configurando el Project SDK como bien dices, a mi se me solucionó. Creo que no tiene mayor implicación pero aun así es inquietante

Answer (score 3):

El problema que presentas no amerita un reporte a Google, pero de hecho si no existe el archivo `adb.exe`, no es posible que puedas ver tu proyecto funcionando, incluso para subir el .apk a tu emulador o dispositivo físico es necesario el [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb).

La ruta donde se encuentra adb.exe es dentro del directorio del sdk en `platform-tools/`:

```
C:\Users\<usuario>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Por el mensaje que comentas, al parecer no existe!

Si este archivo fue borrado, pudo haber sido eliminado por error o como lo mencionas por alguna política de tu antivirus, es importante revises si tu antivirus esta realizando esta acción e incluyas una exepción para excluir este archivo.

Si solo fue eliminado por error, debes instalar nuevamente [SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools).

Ve a `File` > `Settings`, dentro de `System Settings` > `Android SDK` ve a el tab "SDK Tooks" :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez tengas que reinstalar los ADB Tools.

Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Buscas por Android SDK -> Seleccionas la pestaña SDK Tools y después marcas **Android SDK platform tool** y **Android SDK Tools** ...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la retroalimentación, por si alguien lo necesita les dejo un link a un video donde se muestra el procedimiento, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeZKmxt4jkI

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso me faltaba agregar `C:\Users\<Usuario>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` a las variables de entorno de **windows**