# Android Studio - No aparecen los errores de programación

Tags: android, logcat

Desde hace algunas actualizaciones no consigo que `Android Studio` me muestre en que clase y linea está fallando el código.

Simplemente me devuelve:

> *I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24059 SIG: 9*

Con diferentes PID pero siempre esa linea, tanto en modo `Debug` como en `Run`.

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano?

Gracias por adelantado :D

Comment: Estaría bien ver código para poder encontrar el problema, ya que dependiendo del PID puede ser uno u otro el error.

Comment: El código es realmente extenso dado que es una aplicación bastante compleja. Hay alguna lista de errores PID que se pueda consultar por código?

Comment: Lo he intentado buscar pero no he encontrado ninguna lista. la mayoría de los casos era devido a un problema de código o de espacio.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, agrega más detalles por ejemplo de como se muestra la ventana de LogCat @AlvaroEstrada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso posiblemente es un error de [**configuración del LogCat**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat), asegura los siguientes puntos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**A)** Tu dispositivo debe estar conectado, y debe ser seleccionado para que puedas leer información a través del `LogCat`. Si tienes varios dispositivos debes de asegurarte de seleccionar el que esta ejecutando tu aplicación.

**B)** Selecciona el paquete de la aplicación de la cual deseas obtener información,

**C)** se sugiere usar :
`Verbose: se muestran todos los mensajes de registro (configuración predeterminada).`

aunque puedes configurar también :

> - Verbose: se muestran todos los mensajes de registro (configuración predeterminada).
> - Debug: se muestran los mensajes de registro de depuración que son útiles durante el desarrollo únicamente, como también los niveles de
>     mensaje más abajo en esta lista.
> - Info: se muestran los mensajes de registro esperados para uso regular, como también los niveles de mensaje más abajo en esta lista.
> - Warn: se muestran posibles problemas que todavía no se consideran como errores, y los niveles de mensaje, más abajo en esta lista.
> - Error: se muestran los problemas que generaron errores, y también el nivel de mensaje, más abajo en esta lista.
> - Assert: se muestran problemas que el desarrollador espera que nunca sucedan.

**D)** Selecciona la opción "Show only selected application" para que muestre únicamente los mensajes definidos para tu aplicación.

---

Si lo anterior es correcto entonces el problema puede encontrarse en estos puntos:

Si no se ve conectado posiblemente tu cable no esta funcionando correctamente o no esta permitiendo el mostrar información en el LogCat:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra razón por la que no se vea conectado es por un problema del `ADB`:

[android studio error Unable to locate adb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206207/android-studio-error-unable-to-locate-adb)

---

Si tu `movil` es un `Huawei` tienes que habilitar manualmente el mostrar mensajes en el LogCat :

[Android 6.0 no muestra errores logcat Huawei](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12958/android-6-0-no-muestra-errores-logcat-huawei)

Comment: Después de investigar efectivamente el problema era el dispositivo que estaba usando (Huawei).

Principalmente agradecerte la respuesta tan desarrollada, me la guardo porque está muy bien documentada para un futuro.

Muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: Me da gusto que mi respuesta fue de utilidad, saludos!