# jvmti error thread_not_alive

Tags: java, android

Al iniciar una aplicación en Android, en la consola se visualiza el siguiente mensaje:

> E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)

¿Podría alguien ayudarme indicando que significa?

Comment: Añade todo el stacktrace que se muestra, generamente ese error es causado por algún otro

Comment: 11-05 05:26:00.677 27479-27694/packagename E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)

Comment: ese es todo el stacktrace

Comment: Sólo hay una línea de error en el log? Lo normal es algo como lo siguiente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707707/app-crashing-after-theme-update

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Mirnicsoft , en realidad debes buscar el texto donde se muestra "Caused by" seguido del detalle relativo al problema, configura tu LogCat de acuerdo a lo que agrego en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/210799/android-studio-no-aparecen-los-errores-de-programaci%C3%B3n . Te sugiero agregar lo que realiza tu aplicación al iniciar, es importante, por favor no olvides revisar [ask] y realiza el [tour] del sitio, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Creo que no he podido hacerme entender. En realidad la aplicación no se detiene, la aplicación fluye  normálmente. Mi duda se debe al hecho de que en la consola de android studio se visualiza ese mensaje "E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)" y quería saber a que se debe.