# Android Studio 4.0 unable to locate adb desde que se actualizó

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, adb

Actualice Android Studio a la versión 4.0 y no puedo simular mi proyecto de flutter, apareciendo el mensaje "unable to locate adb".

Revisé y todo parece estar en orden

Siguiendo esta respuesta anterior [android studio error Unable to locate adb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206207/android-studio-error-unable-to-locate-adb) probe desinstalar SDK Tool y volverlo a instalar varias veces pero no funciona.

Pueden ver en la imagen que tengo instalado SDK Tools y Command-Line tools porque flutter doctor me dio problemas con este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El adb esta en la carpeta y la dirección la tengo en el antivirus para evitar falsos positivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que falta?

Comment: ¿Intentaste agregando el `path` a las variables de entorno del sistema?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No era necesario volver a publicar tu pregunta, una vez traducida la primera, podiamos volver a abrirla..

Comment: Tengo flutter dentro de las variables de entorno de sistema. Segun vi no necesito otra. O me conviene agregar la de SDK de la carpeta android?

Comment: Volviste a instalar platform-tools? lo puedes hacer desde la ventana del SDK o descargando de google.

Comment: tienes que instalar Platform Tools  , revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206207/android-studio-error-unable-to-locate-adb

Comment: Ya lo hice como 3 veces. Lo desinstale y lo instale de nuevo