# Android Studio - Error: "unable to locate adb"

Tags: android-studio

Buen día, soy bastante nuevo en esto, estoy tratando de instalar android studio, pero al momento de levantar el emulador, me salta el famoso error "unable to locate adb", probé con varias cosas que encontré navegando aqui, pero no funcionaron, les comparto algunas imagenes para que vean la configuración que traigo.
[image: SDK Tools]

[image: Variables de Entorno]

[image: Archivo adb]

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Antes de formular la pregunta, ¿has revisado otros enlaces con el mismo error? [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206207/android-studio-error-unable-to-locate-adb], [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio] Saludos.

Comment: Si, pero no funcionó